# Opening a specific file depending on variables

Tags: python

Okay, so for this GUI I want to read a file depending on what a certain variable result is.  I'll try to explain it in more detail.

So this file takes the input from a drop down menu.  The option the user picks will decide which file is read. The file that is read is then appended into an array, which is then put into another drop down menu.

I want to know if that is possible. Parts of my code is down below.

Earlier Drop down menu:

```
    weapon.set('Sword')
    choices = ['Sword', 'Bow', 'Katana']
    self.weaponMenu = OptionMenu(self,weapon, *choices)
    self.weaponMenu.grid(row =2, column = 2)
```

Reading the file:

```
    self.moves = Label(self, text = "Move")
    self.moves.grid(row = 9, column = 1,)
    move = StringVar()

    weapon = open("%d.txt" %(self.weaponMenu.get()),"r") #reads weapon file
    moves = []
    for line in weapon:
        moves.append(line)
    self.movesMenu = OptionMenu(self, move, *moves)
    self.movesMenu.grid(row =10, column = 1)
```

This is what I tried to do, but I was unable to get it to work.  I could do if statements instead probably, but I want to know if the method I'm trying can work or if there is something else I can do to achieve the same results.

I hope you understood what I wrote and thanks in advance for the help!  Hope I did everything right, I'm still new to stackoverflow.

When I try to execute the file, I get the following error message:

I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\mh4uDamageWindow.py", line 88, in <module>
        app = Application(root)
      File "C:\Python27\mh4uDamageWindow.py", line 10, in __init__
        self.create_widget()
      File "C:\Python27\mh4uDamageWindow.py", line 67, in create_widget
        weapon = open("%d.txt" % (self.weaponMenu.get()),"r") #reads weapon file
    AttributeError: OptionMenu instance has no attribute 'get'
    >>>
```

Comment: What happens when you try the code to indicate it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable set for the `OptionMenu` (`weapon`) and not the widget itself:

```
weapon = open("%s.txt" % (weapon.get()),"r") #reads weapon file
```

If it's not available in the scope where you read the file, add it to `self`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Okay so the code works but it didn't work the way that I thought it'd be, but thanks for your answer.